# How to specify a path to Meson custom_target() command?

Tags: meson-build

I did a simple custom target in Meson:

```
my_build = custom_target('my_build', command: ['../my_script.sh', '-arg1'], build_always_stale: true, output: 'fake')
```

This works OK..., but when I try to use this as subproject from other Meson projects, I get a message that `../my_script.sh` cannot be found.

How do I specify the path to `my_script.sh`, so that the script is always found, no matter called directly in this subproject, or from a root project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path to your `script` and you can do that like this:

`scirpt_path = join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), 'my_script.sh')`

and your custom target will look like this:

`my_build = custom_target('my_build', command: [script_path, '-arg1'], build_always_stale: true, output: 'fake')`

The reason it works for you when you don't have a `subproject` is because you have a structure that your build directory is in the root of your project, so it is possible to find your script with `../my_script.sh`